# Java generic to Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics

I am trying to convert the following java code to Scala, but I get a compiler error

```
dataSource.setDriverClass((Class<? extends Driver>)Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"));
```

I tried the following in Scala

```
dataSource.setDriverClass(Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").asInstanceOf[Class.forName(_ <:Driver)])
```

The error is:-

```
unbound wildcard type
[error]     simpleDriverDataSource.setDriverClass(Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").asInstanceOf[_ <: Driver])
```

I am not able to resolve this, please help.

Thanks,

Amar

Comment: For the future: The line shown in the error very clearly doesn't match the code before it. Please make sure you give the correct error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala equivalent of `Class<? extends Driver>` is `Class[_ <: Driver]`. So

```
dataSource.setDriverClass(Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").
  asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: Driver]])
```

Comment: It said you can accept the answer in 8 mins  and now, in 4 mins :) I will as soon as the mentioned time passes

Comment: @AmarDev Ok, this must be a limitation I don't remember :)